# Selenium and SSO with Firewall

Tags: python, oracle, selenium

I'm new to selenium and was trying to follow a tutorial to run a script that can export an analysis from Oracle OTBI in csv format and save it to my PC. I access Oracle/OTBI via single-sign on on my work computer. When I attempted to run the script I got the attached error message saying I could only access the application from 'Devices or client applications that meet management compliance policy' and prompted me to install the extension shown in the second attachment. I was/am hesitant to install the extension, unless it's necessary and will actually help. I'm open to using MS Edge as the browser if that would help. I didn't know if either would actually help, or if there are security settings my company has enabled that are going to make this impossible? Any assistance or insight is appreciated.

[Error Msg and Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS6C2.png)

Comment: This is a question of your network administration. Contact your IT depends to find a solution.